# Combine .htaccess. ( http to https AND www to non www AND remove trailing slash ) extending normal craftcms .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

I can't manage to combine all above options. Tested with several options and examples only the most examples focusses only on on problem.

The example of .htaccess below is okay but i cannot manage to add the trailing slash combining with www and the http.

Testing with: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

SEO company want's to get rid of trailing slash. I see that most of CraftCMS installs responds to slash AND non slash.

See : craftcms website pricing and pricing/

are also both okay....thats also not ideal while you can introduce duplicate pages for google.

Recap:

http://www.domainname.nl  -> https://domainname.nl
http://www.domainname.nl/products/ -> https://domainname.nl/products (without trailing slash)

https://domainname.nl/products/      https://domainname.nl/products (without trailing slash)

RewriteEngine On

```
# Redirect www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Update 12/06/2018:

Tested now succesfully following version on my server

```
# Redirect www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect /bla/ to /bla
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Tnx, the first piece of code gives a redirect error, after the update piece gives an infinite loop. The test website https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ with the first piece of code after "Try this" gives the following; OK
-https://www.testwebsite.nl/test/ ok (trailing slash) -http://www.testwebsite.nl/test/ ok www and trailing slash removed NOT OK
-http://www.testwebsite.nl/test (returns https://%1/test )
-all the above urls without www (returns https://%1/test ) In case of without www it must also delete the trailing slash en if http then https. without www redirects the above failing to https

Comment: ok, i tested now on my server and found a working version. i update my previous answer.

Comment: Perfect !! Can i buy you a beer ?

I added the default craftcms piece at last. Maybe the second !-d can be deleted now because it's now by the entry blah/ to blah.

Will you place this piece under your solotion (with or without the 2nd sentence?).
I think this is a perfect CraftCMS solution for apache.



# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Keep the second !-d, because the first relates only to the RewriteRules before the next condition block. As soon as a new RewriteCond line is stated only the following Rules apply to them. By the way, the !-d conditions apply if the uri is not a real directory, so they only affect "virtual" paths.